# torcc directory paths not parsed

Tags: configuration, windows, directory

Some if not all of my projects contains folders with symbols in them. Often a leading `#` hash character or `$` dollar sign. When i try to set such a directory within a path like so;

```
DataDirectory Y:\Workspace\$projectFiles\\#include\alpha\data
```

`tor.exe` only gets everything up until the eol char before continuing like so;

```
DataDirectory Y:\Workspace\$projectFiles\
```

could someone add either a

```
eolChar 1|0
```

or

```
eolChar *char*
```

to either options or as a command-line switch? Or a better way to define paths like a dedicated paths file relative to `tor.exe` location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*edited to provide the correct answer only, rather than a hacky workaround*

Encapsulate the whole directory path in `"` characters.

```
DataDirectory "Y:\\Workspace\\$projectFiles\\#include\\alpha\\data"
```

if you wanted to put quotes inside of your directory name, you could by using C style escaping: `\"`

```
DataDirectory "Y:\\Workspace\\\"$projectFiles\"\\#include\\alpha\\data"
```

Comment: yes i know, i use it myself all the time, and in my codes i make sure there is no such thing as an invalid directory character :P but then again i am working in windows. no command flags there. do you have any idea on how to replicate that behavior in a windows command shell?

Comment: Windows does indeed support command line arguments. `start` -> `run` -> `cmd.exe` -> `cd path\to\tor` -> `tor.exe --datadirectory ...`

Comment: i know m8. like the title implies; "torcc directory paths not parsed" that particular option is read from a torcc options file. well all path related options are. but i notice you escape the hash symbol in your command line? '\#' , is this a linux shell feature or something i can use in a options file? maybe its a variable? *confused*

Comment: I'll formulate a full answer I guess...

Comment: Please see my update for a proper solution, it is entirely possible. Had to read the source.

Comment: have you tried this? because that was my original setting, but i had to remove the quotation marks seeing how they stop my tor service from starting.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this.

Comment: the hash signs in my options file is parsed as comment starters even if the path they are in is quoted. this is very strange, can you you give me the name or link of the source file you saw this behavior? and also if there is a written documentation that states that quoted lines escapes special characters i'd love to see that. i couldn't find it in the online documentation but i might have missed it. and if so, your answer will be marked as correct

Comment: https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/common/util.c#n2852

Comment: https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/doc/tor.1.txt#n133

Comment: https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/common/util.c#n2907 I wonder if window's default use of '\r\n' instead of '\n' would break this parsing..? What error do you see when you use the quoted method?

Comment: "[warn] Error while parsing configuration: Excess data after quoted string" <- if I terminate a quote-escaped line with \r\n instead of \n

Comment: tor seems to parse the CRLF's from the options file just fine. i tried with just LF's but it mattered not to my problem. i've read through the sources you supplied and it doesn't seem there is any way to escape the hash character as of now.  my error is : [warn] Error while parsing configuration: Invalid escape sequence in quoted string

Comment: You may need to review your escaping, then. It's happening during unescape_string: https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/common/util.c#n2744

Comment: fml. escape the directory slashes e.g. "Y:\\Workspace\\$projectFiles\\#include\\alpha\\data"

Comment: HAH!!! "Y:\\Workspace\\$projectFiles\\#include\\alpha\\data" of course. my logic's was all twisted. instead of trying to see what should be escaped in the path i was convinced it was an error while parsing a single UN-escapable character. you have solved my problem m8. thanks a billion. edit your answer with the slashes thing and it's a 100%.